# How to share selected folders with selected users in Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have few folders but i want separate users to see separate folders on their Desktop when they log in.

Is it possible in AD

The client Machine are XP professional , window Vista

Comment: Does it need to be on the desktop?  How about just mapping those folders as drives through a login script?

Comment: IF i do that then i have to go into user computer and then add as drive . I want to do in active dirtectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example logon script that maps network shares based off of user's Active Directory group membership can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758918(WS.10).aspx

You can specify the Logon script on the "Profile" tab of the user properties dialog in the Active Directory Users and Computers MMC or via Group Policy.  The "Profile" method would typically be used for users with legacy (Pre-Win2K) computers, and Group Policy would be for everything Win2K or later.

The setting in Group Policy is found under "User Configuration"--> "Windows Settings"--> "Scripts (Logon/Logoff)"--> "Logon".

Great FAQ on this topic here: http://www.rlmueller.net/LogonScriptFAQ.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can map the drive through an Active Directory logon script, as l0c0b0x said.